# css3 override the transition-timing-function

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How do i disable the 'transition-timing-function' effect in css3

I am using twitter bootstrap accordion effect. when i click on the first tab the items are coming from right to left.

Is there any way to remove the effect.

```
.collapsing{
  position:relative;
  height:0;
  overflow:hidden;

 -webkit-transition-timing-function:ease;
 -o-transition-timing-function:ease;
 transition-timing-function:ease;

 -webkit-transition-duration:.35s;
 -o-transition-duration:.35s;
 transition-duration:.35s;

 -webkit-transition-property:height,visibility;
 -o-transition-property:height,visibility;
 transition-property:height,visibility
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do mean the transition effect, then I propose a

```
#accordion-id {
    transition: none !important;
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    -o-transition: none !important;
}
```

solution.

Because the `transition-timing-function`, `transition-duration` and `transition-property` is like sub property of `transition`.

I grab the syntax from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition) showing

```
[ none | <single-transition-property> ] || <time> || <timing-function> || <time> ]
```

as transition property syntax in CSS.

Note : Vendor prefix not tested.

Comment: but still i am not able to overriding the class. please see my updated image

Comment: Eh..
Does my answer helped you? Or does it need some modification..?